# Issue with Postgress and Google Maps Markers

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to draw points onto a map based on data in a Postgres DB, can anyone tell me why this won't work.. I'm scratching my head trying to figure it out.

I'm pulling data from a Postgres DB using this PHP code, which appears to be working just fine:

```
<?php
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
      // Connecting, selecting database
$dbconn = pg_connect(**MY LOGON DEETS**)
          or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());
$lat1 = $_GET['lat1'];
$lat2 = $_GET['lat2'];
$lng1 = $_GET['lng1'];
$lng2 = $_GET['lng2'];

$pin_points = 'SELECT lat,lng,price,address_string FROM house_price_data_db.main where lat>=$1 and lat<=$2 and lng<=$3 and lng>=$4';
$result_pinpoints_points = pg_query_params($dbconn,$pin_points,array($lat1,$lat2,$lng1,$lng2)) or die('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error());
$pin_points_array = array();
while($r = pg_fetch_assoc($result_pinpoints_points)) {
    $pin_points_array[] = $r;
}
header("Content-type: application/json" ); // set the header to json 
echo(json_encode(array_values($pin_points_array), JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK)); // this will return json
pg_close($dbconn);
?>
```

To try and draw points on a map, using the code outlined below. I feel there's an error/issue with my Javascript, but I can't figure it out:

```
 var lat1=55.55;
 var lat2=56.05;
 var lng1=8.00;
 var lng2=8.45;
 function setMarkers(){
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
     xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
     xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      var pinpoints = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
      var marker;
      var i=0;
      var lat;
      var lng;
      var price;
      var address;
      var post_latlng;
      var content;
      for (i = 0;i<pinpoints.length;i++){ 
        a=pinpoints[i];
        lat=parseFloat(a["lat"]);
        lng=parseFloat(a["lng"]);
        price=parseFloat(a["price"]);
        address=String(a["address_string"]);

        post_latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
        content = "<b>Price:</b> " + price +  '</br>' + "<b>Address:</b> " + address;  

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({  
          map: map, 
          title: address,
          position: post_latlng  
        });
        map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click', (function(marker,content,infowindow){ 
          return function(){
           infowindow.setContent(content);
           infowindow.open(map,marker);
          };
        })(marker,content,infowindow)); 
      }
    }
   }
   xmlhttp.open("GET","pinpoints.php?lat1="+lat1+"&lat2="+lat2+"&lng1="+lng1+"&lng2="+lng2,false);
   xmlhttp.send();
 }
```

For some reason it won't work, I expect the function to call the PHP script, return an array and then use this array's contents and the Javscript function to draw markers on a map, that when clicked display some information. When I use Firebug I'm not getting any errors. Any suggestions on how to resolve this are more than welcome.

Comment: What do you mean "It won't work".  What do you expect to happen (it should draw points on a map?) and then what actually happens?

Comment: @couling I expect the function to call the PHP script, return an array and then use this array's contents and the Javascript function to draw markers on a map, that when clicked display some information. When I run the function, it calls the PHP function, and then goes no further.

Comment: Your script works for me with a valid response( and as you said the PHP-script works fine, so the response must be valid JSON). Based on your code I may only guess that `map` is not accessible inside `setMarkers()`. When my assumption is wrong you'll need to post more code.

Comment: CodeReview is for working code only, not code explanations or to understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: Try changing the line:
xmlhttp.open("GET","pinpoints.php?lat1="+lat1+"&lat2="+lat2+"&lng1="+lng1+"&lng2="+lng2,false);
TO
xmlhttp.open("GET","pinpoints.php?lat1="+lat1+"&lat2="+lat2+"&lng1="+lng1+"&lng2="+lng2,true);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my code was working ok, but that the query I was sending to the database to test the function didn't have any returned rows.